# Problems related to a resizable component

Tags: reactjs

I am writing a component that allows the width of it's child element to change if you click on its right border and drag it.

I have a few problems however. First off, it's awkward to drag the div element, because if the mouse enters the other element to the right while dragging, the dragging state is lost and bugs out.

Also, I currently show the resize cursor when the point is within 5 pixels of the right border, which works fine when inside the resizable div. However, if you approach the border from the right (mouse inside other div), you cannot select it, even though you're within 5 pixels.

Another problem is that when I drag the mouse and resize the div, the mouse selects the text it drags over.

Lastly, because the element has to rerender each time it's width is changed, I've noticed that the performance is not always smooth.

Any advice on how to mitigate these problems?

```
Resizable = React.createClass({

  propTypes: {
    id       : React.PropTypes.string,
    class    : React.PropTypes.string,
    width    : React.PropTypes.number,
    onResize : React.PropTypes.func,
    onAction : React.PropTypes.func,
  },

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      showResizeCursor : false,
      canResize        : false,
    };
  },

  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
    };
  },

  _handleMouseMove: function(event) {
    var node       = React.findDOMNode(this);
    var offsets    = node.getBoundingClientRect();
    var divLeft    = offsets.left;
    var divRight   = offsets.right;
    var mouseX     = event.clientX;

    var maxWidth = this.props.maxWidth || this.props.width;
    var minWidth = this.props.minWidth || this.props.width;
    var newWidth = mouseX - divLeft + 200;
    var isWithinBounds = newWidth <= maxWidth && newWidth >= minWidth;

    if (this.state.canResize && isWithinBounds) {
      this.props.onResize(newWidth);
    }

    var difference = Math.abs(divRight - mouseX);

    if (difference < 4) {
      return this.setState({ showResizeCursor: true });
    }

    if (this.state.showResizeCursor) {
      this.setState({ showResizeCursor: false });
    }
  },

  _handleMouseUp: function() {
    this.setState({ canResize: false });
  },

  _handleMouseDown: function() {
    if (this.state.showResizeCursor) {
      this.setState({ canResize: true });
    }
  },

  render: function() {
    var style = {
      width : this.state.width,
    };

    if (this.state.showResizeCursor) { style.cursor = 'col-resize'; }

    return (
      <div id={this.props.id}
        style       ={style}
        className   ={this.props.class}
        onMouseDown ={this._handleMouseDown}
        onMouseUp   ={this._handleMouseUp}
        onMouseMove ={this._handleMouseMove}
        onMouseLeave={this._handleMouseUp}


      >
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Example usage:

```
render: function() {
...
return (
  <Wrapper>
    <Resizable
      id       = {'list-view'}
      width    = {this.state.listViewWidth}
      maxWidth = {this.state.listViewMaxWidth}
      minWidth = {this.state.listViewMinWidth}
      onResize = {this._handleListViewResize}
    >
      {first_column_that_should_be_resizable}
    </Resizable>
    {second_column_not_resizeable}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many different concerns here...

> First off, it's awkward to drag the div element, because if the mouse enters the other element to the right while dragging, the dragging state is lost and bugs out.

This is a very common issue when you start coding your first drag&drop alike behavior. You should not listen the mousedown, mousemove and mouseup events on the same element, you should only listen the mousedown event and in that handler start listening the other two but on the body of the document. This way, you have a global handler and you will not have problems with the mouse getting over other elements.

> Also, I currently show the resize cursor when the point is within 5 pixels of the right border, which works fine when inside the resizable div. However, if you approach the border from the right (mouse inside other div), you cannot select it, even though you're within 5 pixels.

I would suggest you to use only CSS for this. Is what it is for :)

> Another problem is that when I drag the mouse and resize the div, the mouse selects the text it drags over.

Yep, just CSS. Once your mousedown handler is executed add a special CSS class to your element and put something like this in your CSS.

```
.disable-select {
  -webkit-user-select: none;  
  -moz-user-select: none;    
  -ms-user-select: none;      
  user-select: none;
}
```

> Lastly, because the element has to rerender each time it's width is changed, I've noticed that the performance is not always smooth.

I don't think React is your best option in here. I would just add this behavior using jQuery and the lifecycle methods like `componentDidMount`. This way, you can resize the div using plain jQuery (on every mouse move) and then just apply the final state (that is, the final size) to your component on the mouseup handler.

Comment: How can I apply a specific css cursor when I hover over the border of the div?

Comment: Is not that easy, actually. I would suggest you to take a quick look to the Resizer plugin in jQuery UI (https://jqueryui.com/resizable/). If you inspect the resizable div, you will find that jQuery creates a set of divs with position absolute on each of the borders.

Comment: I would definitevely use that plugin and connect it with React through life cycle methods. Is the easiest way unless you really want to do something different/crazy in your UI.